# Is this integration method correct?

Tags: complex-analysis

*Let $\psi_{(a,b)}$ denote the circle center $a$ radius $b$*

> Show that
>   $$I = \int_{\psi(1,1)}\frac{1}{1+e^z}dz = 0$$

Here's what I did, and admittedly it is a bit drawn out, however I'm more concerned with the correctness of the method rather than an easier alternative:

$$u = 1 + e^z \implies dz = \frac{du}{e^z}$$
$$\implies I = \int_{\psi(1,1)}\frac{du}{u(u-1)} = \int_{\psi(1,1)}(u-1)^{-1}-u^{-1} du$$
$$\implies I = \int_0^{2\pi}ie^{it}(e^{-it} - (e^{it} + 1)^{-1}) dt$$
$$\text{Take }v = 1 + e^{it}\text{ and hence }v|_{t = 0} = 2 = v|_{t=2\pi}$$
By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we have $I = 0$ after substituting $v$ for $t$ in $I$

Comment: You have to change the path of integration when you make the substitution.

Comment: Don't forget to change the domain of integration when changing variables!  If $z$ is ranging along the circle of radius 1 centered at 1, then $u = 1 + e^z$ ranges along the image of that circle under the mapping $z \mapsto 1 + e^z$ (I'm not sure if there's a nicer description for this set).

Comment: I knew there was something off, thanks!

Comment: An easier (?) alternative (yes, I know you don't want one ) is to note that your function is holomorphic on an open set containing your circle so the integral over the closed path is $0$ by [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem)

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch as a matter of fact that's what I tried to do at first, but didn't succeed.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch knowing this is the case motivates me to try again :)

Comment: @Threnody Where did it go wrong (maybe my argument has a loophole that I am not seeing)

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I actually did it again and got it correct, I must've been confused then :) $u_x = e^x \cos y$, $u_y = -e^x \sin y$, $v_x = \sin(y)e^x$ and $v_y = \cos(y)e^x$
Thanks :)